# Why is evidence lower bound concave in the parameters?

Tags: expectation-maximization, variational-bayes

The expectation maximization algorithm maximizes the evidence lower bound given by the following equation:
$$ELBO = \Sigma_zQ(z)log\frac{p(x,z;\theta)}{Q(z)}$$

Now, the mechanism of the EM algorithm is given somewhat by the following picture

[image]

Here it is assumed that the elbo is a concave function. I can see log is a concave function but it is concave in its arguments which here is the entire $\frac{p(x,z;\theta)}{Q(z)}$. I understand $Q$ is computed as the first step itself and is now a constant for each data point. But, how are we concluding that $log(p(x,z;\theta))$ is concave in $\theta$?